Wordpress ultimate members plugin multiple role register link
I have two roles (patients and nurses)
inside the login page there is a secondary button which is register. both of the patient and the nurse login page, the register button redirect to the same link which is nurse sign up page.
Is there a way to make the secondary button (register button) of the patient to redirect to the right registration page?

https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/87-adding-a-registration-form
